# How do I avoid getting DeprecationWarning from inside dependencies with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I often get lots of deprecations from libraries that are outside my control and I do not want to pollute test executions with them.

How can I avoid this without risking to disable deprecations from my own code?

Example:

```
================================================================================ warnings summary ==================================================================================
.tox/py27-ansible25-unit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/toml/decoder.py:47
  /Users/ssbarnea/os/molecule/.tox/py27-ansible25-unit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/toml/decoder.py:47: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \.
    TIME_RE = re.compile("([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]{3,6}))?")

.tox/py27-ansible25-unit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py:424
  /Users/ssbarnea/os/molecule/.tox/py27-ansible25-unit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py:424: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
    rc_exc_regex = re.compile("(ErrorReturnCode|SignalException)_((\d+)|SIG[a-zA-Z]+)")

.tox/py27-ansible25-unit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:152
  /Users/ssbarnea/os/molecule/.tox/py27-ansible25-unit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:152: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \*
```

Answer (score 8):

I won't repeat `pytest` docs on the general topic of warnings capturing, for the sake of reference: [Warnings Capture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html). From here, you can narrow the warnings captured by stricter filters. The [filter format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warning-filter) is

```
{action}:{message}:{category}:{module}:{lineno}
```

with elements skippable. Examples to paste in your `pytest.ini`, from general to specific:

#### ignore everything

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore:
```

#### ignore all `DeprecationWarning`s

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

#### ignore all `DeprecationWarning`s with `invalid escape sequence` in message

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore:.*invalid escape sequence.*:DeprecationWarning
```

#### ignore `DeprecationWarning`s only in `toml.decoder` module

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:toml.decoder
```

#### ignore `DeprecationWarning`s only in `toml.decoder` module on line 47

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning:toml.decoder:47
```

#### ignore `DeprecationWarning`s only in `toml.decoder` module, only on line 47 and only with `invalid escape sequence` in message:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore:.*invalid escape sequence.*:DeprecationWarning:toml.decoder:47
```